# ngrok doesn't lift my local django web server

Tags: django, ngrok

I have problems with negrok, it does not raise my local django web server, a few days ago everything worked correctly but a normal day, without having touched anything, it stopped working.

Run the following:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Everything works normally and correctly.

---

Now I execute the following, in order to raise the local django server:

```
./ngrok http 8000
```

ngrok runs correctly without any problem but when accessing the ngrok link, the page is loading and everything is blank and does not work ....

This appears in ngrok:

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                (Ctrl+C to quit)

Session Status                online                                                                                     
Account                       Julio (Plan: Free)                                                                         
Version                       2.3.34                                                                                     
Region                        United States (us)                                                                         
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                      
Forwarding                    http://33822c5a.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:8000                                          
Forwarding                    https://33822c5a.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:8000                                         

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                
                              2       0       0.03    0.01    0.20    0.21                                               

HTTP Requests                                                                                                            
-------------                                                                                                            

GET /                          400 Bad Request                                                                           
GET /                          400 Bad Request
```

And this appears in django:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 25, 2019 - 17:23:19
Django version 2.2.2, using settings 'ibme_proyect.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '33822c5a.ngrok.io'. You may need to add '33822c5a.ngrok.io' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Bad Request: /
[25/Sep/2019 17:25:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 68119
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '33822c5a.ngrok.io'. You may need to add '33822c5a.ngrok.io' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Bad Request: /
[25/Sep/2019 17:25:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 68254
```

I add the ngrok host (`33822c5a.ngrok.io`) in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` and stop giving django error, and access the ngrok link and I know that it loads again, it doesn't load the HTML, nothing, everything blank ...

Any solution? :(

Comment: After you added the Ngrok url to allowed hosts, will you copy and paste the output of the terminal?

Comment: try run this: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` . Then reload page again after add ngrok host in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

Answer (score 0):

try
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
this will allow tunneling every ngrok run :)

Comment: did not work for me